# Laravel cors not working on Apache server

Tags: laravel, apache, cors

I have a laravel api app, all is working fine on localhost (IIS), I can do a GET request successfully, I have the same app on Apache server suddenly my api throws a CORS`enter code here` error, I'm using the laravel-cors plugin

I've tried allowing headers on the .htaccess file to no avail.

Below is a truncated version of my kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        //'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        //'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,

    ];
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the error?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:/xxxxx.com/api/dummy/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got it to work by including the headers directly to the methods/functions within my controller.

```
....    
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
return $response;
```

A bit hacky, but will have to do for now